# What are the names of the forces acting upon the side of a vessel?

Tags: flight-controls, navigation, terminology

People often refer to the four forces in navigation as weight, lift, thrust and drag. Are there separate names for the forces acting upon the side of a craft?

Comment: What do you mean by "side"? left and right? Remember that drag and lift are just arbitrary decomposition of the total of aerodynamic forces such that lift is vertical and opposed to weight.

Comment: @ManuH I sure wish the industry would come up with a term to differentiate the two definitions of lift. It would avoid much confusion

Comment: @ManuH Lift is NOT `vertical and opposed to weight`. Lift is perpendicular to the airflow.

Comment: @Federico does this mean lift and weight have the same direction when the airplane is upside down, i.e. with a negative load factor (e.g. during an aileron roll)?

Comment: @ManuH depends. usually no, as you will have an AoA such that the lift will be negative (in the aircraft reference frame) and thus still pointing up.

Comment: @Federico That's what I meant: pointing up (frame of reference: aircraft) but negative. I understand that if you keep the aircraft's frame of reference, the direction won't change but the value will go from positive to negative. There is still one point I don't understand: perpendicular to airflow is not the same as perpendicular to aircraft (the difference being linked with AoA)

Comment: @ManuH probably is better to pass in chat. but shortly: `pointing up (frame of reference: aircraft)` no, if it is "negative" it points down in that frame. It is "up" for an external observer. `perpendicular to airflow is not the same as perpendicular to aircraft (the difference being linked with AoA)` that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

As we engineers are extremely boring people, and given the fact that a name seems not to be available, we generally refer to them simply as "side forces".

Or, at least, I never encountered a different term on any of the textbooks that I have read.

Comment: *Lateral* and sometimes *transverse* or *cross-* are also used to qualify these forces.